# Calling method inbetween Fragments which are in tabs

Tags: android, methods, android-fragments, android-activity, android-tabhost

I currently have a few fragments which are all organised in tabs and i want fragment A to call a method in frag B. So I know I need to call the activity which then calls the function in B, I have seen people mentioning to use

```
ExampleFragment fragment = (ExampleFragment)  
 getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.example_fragment);


fragment.<specific_function_name>();
```

I am having a problem though as my fragments are added with a tab listener not a fragmentmanager so I have no idea how to use this to call a method. Here is how my tabs are added.

```
public class fifaActivity extends Activity {


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setTitle(TourneyName);
    bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    bar.setIcon(R.drawable.fifa);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


        bar.addTab(bar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Tables")
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<fifa.tables>(this, "tables",
                            fifa.tables.class)));

        bar.addTab(bar
            .newTab()
            .setText("Knockouts")
            .setTabListener(
                    new TabListener<fifa.knockouts>(this, "tables",
                            fifa.knockouts.class)));




    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        bar.setSelectedNavigationItem(savedInstanceState.getInt("tab", 0));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex())

}

public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;
    private final Bundle mArgs;
    private Fragment mFragment;

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        this(activity, tag, clz, null);
    }

    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz,
            Bundle args) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
        mArgs = args;

        mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);
        if (mFragment != null && !mFragment.isDetached()) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = mActivity.getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment == null) {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),
                    mArgs);
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }


}
```

Any help on how to call a method from the fifa.tables fragment to the fifa.knockouts fragment will be hugely appreciated.

Thanks, Oli

Comment: When exactly(at what moment) do you want to call the method from fragment B to fragment A?

Comment: when I am currently viewing fragment B and I click a button inside that layout.

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an interface the will be implemented by the hosting Activity.
The Fragment A will hold reference to the Activity as this interface instance, and when it wants to call the function in Fragment B it will call the function in the interface.
In the interface implementation in the hosting Activity, the Activity will made a call to the function in Fragment B.

Edit:

I will show some examples.

You need to create an interface that 'Fragment A' will use to call method in 'Fragment B', for example:

```
public interface FragmentBMethodsCaller{
    void callTheMethodInFragmentB();
}
```

Now, you need to implement it. Let's say your activity is called HostActivity:

```
public class HostActivity extends Activity implements FragmentBMethodsCaller{
    ...
    public void callTheMethodInFragmentB(){
         --Implementation--
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, last thing you need to call it inside Fragment A:

```
FragmentBMethodsCaller fbmc = (FragmentBMethodsCaller)getActivity();
fbmc.callTheMethodInFragmentB();
```

Good luck.

Comment: Im sorry but I do not fully understand what you mean here. Do you mean create a new class? what do you mean by create an interface?

Comment: This may help.  Here's Google's guide to what he is trying to explain.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity

Comment: but where in this do I add the calling of a method in fragment B, at no point do i say fragmentb.doTask(). or is there anywhere that has a reference to say what the fragment is i want to do the activity in.

Comment: this still does not help me find the Fragment I need to call at all, I have no way of setting an ID for the fragment and also I cannot set a tag for it. So how do I actually call fragmentB??

Comment: First of all, when you create the TabListeners that create the Fragments, you are using the same tag for both ("tables"), so please fix it. Second thing, when you create the TabListener you give him a tag and it creates the fragment with the tag. Just save the tag of Fragment B, and inside  the function `callTheMethodInFragmentB()` use this tag to find the Fragment, and call the function you want, just like you do inside the TabListener. `mFragment = mActivity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);`